# nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Udemy講座でNoMethodErrorで躓いております
current_priceにget_priceの値を代入して
if文で条件分岐をしているのですが
エラーになります
current_priceに値が入っていないのでは？と思ったのですが
プログラム起動後、puts current_priceにて
値は表示されておりました
原因を御教授願います
環境はCloud9,ruby 2.4.0p0,Rails 5.1.4

```
require './method.rb'

while(1)
current_price = get_price
puts current_price
if current_price > 450000
    puts "現在の価格は45万円を越えてます"
elsif current_price < 400000
    puts "現在の価格は40万円を下回ってます"
else
    puts "現在価格は40~45万円の間です"

end
sleep(1)
end

get_price
order(side,price,size)
get_balance(coin_name)

test.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: 条件分岐の”>”を全て”==”に変えるとエラーが出なくなりました

Comment: puts nilは改行を出力するだけなので見逃していませんか。目視確認するのであればputsではなくpを使って確認してみてください

Comment: current_price = get_price　→　474315.0
puts current_price　　　　→　空白
p current_price　　　　　　→　nil
p current_price.class　　　→　NilClass
変数に代入後、即空になってる様です

Comment: get_price の中身の問題かと...回答に書かれてる内容だけでは何のことか分かりません。まずは、get_priceの中身を記載した方が、解決への早道だと思いますよ。

Answer (score 1):

`get_price` が `nil` を返しており、nil は大小比較することができない (比較のメソッドを持っていない) ためです。

```
nil == 100
# => false
nil > 100
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

大まかには次のいずれかの処理を行うことになるでしょう。(これが全てでは無いですし、プログラムの目的によってよりふさわしい処理があるかもしれません。)

1. `nil` の判定をして、メッセージを出力する・プログラムを終了するなどの処理を行う。(`current_price.nil?` で判定できます)
2. `nil` の場合には、ふさわしいデフォルト値を代入する。(`current_price = get_price || 0` または `current_price = 0 if current_price.nil?` など。0がふさわしいかどうかはプログラムの目的によって異なります。)

Comment: 回答有難うございます。nilで大小比較は出来ないことは承知しておりますが、while文内でcurrent_price = get_priceで代入して、
puts current_priceで、代入された０以上の数字が表示されている状態で問題が起きております

Answer (score -1):

正しいか何故なのかは未だわかりませんが、get_priceのJSON形式のハッシュ変換で
記述を変えたらClassがNilClassからFlootに変わり、条件分岐内でもnilならずに起動できました

（問題時）
response_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts response_hash["mid_price"]

（訂正後）
response_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
p response_hash["mid_price"]